# LaTeX error file 'ulem.sty' not found in windows

Tags: packages, lyx, miktex, windows

while trying to read a file as PDF (`pdflatex`) I get this error:

```
LaTeX error: file 'ulem.sty' not found
```

I have searched far and wide on the web, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Things I have already tried:

- Reinstalling LyX
- Tools -> reconfigure

Without any results unfortunatly.

Any help would be appreciated!

BTW: I am using MiKTex 2.9.

Comment: Lyx does not install packages: that is down to your TeX distribution. Which one do you use? (MiKTeX or TeX Live are the common choices.)

Comment: I am using MiKTeX 2.9, I will update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain `ulem.sty` here: https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ulem/ulem.sty

If you put it into the catalogue (folder) with your files, it should be enough to compile your work.

Comment: Hmm well, I saved the file as "ulem.sty" then pasted it to 'C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools' After wich I reconfigured my Lyx with "tools" -> "Reconfigure" and then I restarted LyX. But the program still gives me the error :(

Comment: @Gutanoth Please try put it in the folder with the file you are working on. It is a temporary solution, but should work.

Comment: Indeed this works! So there is no permanent solution for this problem? Like a package I could download to complete LyX?

Comment: @Gutanoth Ihave this package in the following path: \MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\ltxmisc\ulem.sty So probably installing ltxmisc will solve the problem.

Comment: @Gutanoth I know nothing about MiKTeX but I think it has a "install packages on the fly" option. You could try that. Or, if you want to try Ubuntu, you can easily search packages for a file and install the package without having to find it online.

Comment: Expanding on @scottkosty's suggestion: `apt-cache search ulem` returns the texlive-generic-recommended package, and `apt-cache policy texlive-generic-recommended` shows the installation status.